# List comprehension error due to incompatible types, does work with if statement

Tags: python, typeerror, list-comprehension

I received the following error whilst running my code. I was basically trying to find the lowest year in a csv file, as a school exercise (no pandas). I wrote `minyear = [regyear if regyear < minyear else minyear]`; this gave the below error. However if i write the exact same without list comprehension I get no error. Now I wonder why I can not use the list comprehension? I am a beginner and thus it is probably something dumb. Thank you!

> solution.py:14: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[int]", variable has type "int")

```
def first_registration(filename: str) -> int:
    """Returns the earliest year a patron registered."""
    # TODO
    minyear = 2022
    with open(filename, "r") as fcsv:
        next(fcsv)
        for user_data in fcsv:
            user = user_data.split(",")
            regyear = int(user[10])
            if regyear < minyear:
                minyear = regyear
            #  minyear = [regyear if regyear < minyear else minyear]
        return minyear
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not a list comprehesion!

List comprehesion (as name suggests) creates a list and your `minyear` needs to be an int. Here you tried to use [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) and you are quite close. The only thing is to remove square brackets:

```
minyear = regyear if regyear < minyear else minyear
```

With brackets, you create a list with one element.